# Bug while running Android Emulator with setContentView in Android Studio

Tags: android

I met a bug while running Android Emulator with setContentView in Android Studio.

The actually result while running in Android emulator is shown in the screenshot.[Actually result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zQEx.png)

I don't know why.

If anyone can reply, I will be fully appreciated.

Basic info:
Here I will list in used basic info of this question.
About project,
MainActivity.java , activity_main.xml , activity_1.xml are both in the zip file (stackoverflow_v1.zip) which available at Github.
https://github.com/40843245/Question/blob/main/stackoverflow/Android%20Studio/setContentView/project/zip/stackoverflow_v1.zip
About Android Emulator, Pixel Pro 33.
About Android Studio, Android Studio Flamigo 2022.1
[Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8NwQ.png)

Use Debugger in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

replace

`activity_main_textview_1 = activity_main.findViewById(R.id.activity_1_TextView_1);`

with

`activity_main_textview_1 = activity_main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_TextView_1);`

When you use **findViewById()**, be sure the View's id is in your XML file

Your **activity_main.xml** doesn't have an id called **activity_1_TextView_1**